# How to animate background of a Sprite-Kit game just like the login screen of Instagram iOS app?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, instagram, gradient

I am creating a game in Sprite-Kit and would want to animate the background in the similar fashion as Instagram does on its login screen.

Basically, I just want to know how to have a background in my game just like the Instagram app has on its login screen, i.e the pink colored screen which gradually changes to violet color and then to red with a very subtle flowing effect from right to left. I know how to animate the gradient but that subtle effect that I'm talking about which gives quite a view of a gas or stream flowing (I'm in love with that effect) doesn't seem to be happening.

Comment: And it is likely to keep not happening unless you show us at least some of what you have done instead of asking us to steal or re-implement proprietary code for you.

Comment: You are very much right Mr. MAD, but you are eligible to say so only if you know the answer. So, do you know the answer Mr. Physicst??

Comment: What you are asking for is a lot of work and is very broad,  SO is not the place for these type of questions.  Perhaps  the Apple developer forums would be a better place.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a framework such as `BackgroundVideoiOS` as seen on [github](https://github.com/Guzlan/BackgroundVideoiOS)

Comment: SpriteKit already contains SKVideoNode for this type of functionality.

Comment: That would increase the game size I suppose. I want it done through code only