# How to change the background color gradually just like the login UI of the Instagram app?

Tags: ios, colors, background, instagram

Recently, I have downloaded the Instagram app and found the login page of the app was so cool, especially the background color animation-- change one color to another color gradually.
I just want to know how to implement it.[SCREEN SHOOT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6NyuT.png)
Is it use a video which changes the color with a circle on the basis of the time?
Or some other methods? Can anyone tell me? Thanks!

Comment: there are lots of answers to this - you want to Animate the background color, like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34383678/animate-uiview-background-color-swift, or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28301411/animate-background-color-of-uibutton-from-whitecolor-to-redcolor

Comment: Thanks.But maybe I didn't describe it clearly.The above methods with the link just change the color from one to another directly with a time interval, not gradually. And In the login page of the  Instagram, it looks like that there's  a flowing effect(something sliding) from right to left behind the background.

Comment: ok - looks like the link is just an image, not a video.  You could use an animation to slide in a background view, and changing the color directly could be either a timer event, or the completion of one of your animations

Comment: Ok, I will have a try, thanks again! And I  found the similar question with the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38896903/how-to-animate-background-of-a-sprite-kit-game-just-like-the-login-screen-of-ins) just now.